# Creating an html table with the date of a MySQL table, orded by price

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm making a wishlist web-app (for lack of a better term.) for my family, that's using php and mysql.

I have a table called 'TEST', and I've filled it with a bunch of test values and I'm trying to display it by Ascending price, like so...

[image: Terminal output]

...but in an html table like this one.

[image: HTML table of SQL table]

The code I've used to generate the second image is this...

```
    if (isset($_POST['button1'])) 
    { 
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$m->get('NAME');
      //Feeds the statement to the mysql connection
      $resultPrice = $conn->query($sql); 

      echo "button 1 has been pressed.<br>";
      echo "$ m :".$m->get('NAME').".<br>";

      echo "<table id='results'>";
      echo "<tr ><td class='itemPrice'>PRICE</td><td class='itemID'> ID </td><td> ITEM </td><td> URL/LOCATOIN </td><td> NOTES </td></tr> "; 
      if ($resultPrice->num_rows != 0) 
      {
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $resultPrice->fetch_assoc()) 
          {
             if($row["id"] % 2 != 0) {echo"<tr class='rowDark'><td class='itemPrice' style='background-color:#69f;color:#fff;'> $" . $row["PRICE"]. " </td><td class='itemID'> " . $row["id"]. " </td><td> " . $row["ITEM"]. " </td><td> " . $row["URL"]. " </td><td> " . $row["NOTES"]. " </td></tr> ";}
           else {echo                     "<tr>                <td class='itemPrice' style='background-color:#69f;color:#fff;'> $" . $row["PRICE"]. " </td><td class='itemID'> " . $row["id"]. " </td><td> " . $row["ITEM"]. " </td><td> " . $row["URL"]. " </td><td> " . $row["NOTES"]. " </td></tr> ";}
        }
        //clear $Person after the data is displayed for the next update
    }
```

I've tried find a way I could adapt my existing code to order the data by price, but I haven't been able to do so. If anyone has an idea that can help, It would be of great help.

### UPDATE/EDIT

I have tried the following code:

```
    1    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$m->get('NAME')."ORDER BY PRICE";
    2    $resultPrice0 = $conn->query($query); 

    3    echo "<table id='results1'>";
    4    echo "<tr ><td class='itemPrice'>PRICE </td><td class='itemID'> ID </td><td> ITEM </td><td> URL/LOCATOIN </td><td> NOTES </td></tr> ";

    5    if ($resultPrice->num_rows != 0) 
    6    {
    7       // output data of each row
    8       while($row0 = $resultPrice0->fetch_assoc()) 
    9        {
    10         echo"<tr><td> $" . $row["PRICE"]. " </td><td class='itemID'> " . $row["id"]. " </td><td> " . $row["ITEM"]. " </td><td> " . $row["URL"]. " </td><td> " . $row["NOTES"]. " </td></tr> ";              
    11       }
    12    }
```

I get the following error.:

```
  Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /path/to/index.php on line 8
```

I am new to php and mysql, so I don't know what this means.

Again. Thank your for what ever help is offered.

Comment: Why there is `resultPrice0->fetch_assoc()` shouldn't it have been `resultPrice->fetch_assoc()` notice the 0 in former statement

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ORDER BY` tag.

This syntax orders rows by a ascending or descending order by provided field.

```
// Show highest price to lowest price

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$m->get('NAME') . " ORDER BY PRICE DESC";


// Show lowest price to highest price

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$m->get('NAME') . " ORDER BY PRICE ASC";
```

Comment: @dzunepwnsipod72, add space before `ORDER BY` and it will work. Corrected code: $query = `"SELECT * FROM ".$m->get('NAME')." ORDER BY PRICE";`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$m->get('NAME') . " ORDER BY price";
```

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$m->get('NAME')."ORDER BY PRICE";

You have a mistake here it will look like SELECT * FROMtable_name ORDER BY PRICE because you don't have space before order by. 

Make it $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$m->get('NAME')." ORDER BY PRICE";